# Bash : Remove values present in file from a variable

Tags: bash

I have a variable which has values such as

```
"abc.def.ghi aa.bbb.ccc kk.lll.mmm ppp.qqq.lll"
```

and a file which has values

```
kk.lll.mmm    
abc.def.ghi
```

I want to remove these values from the variable. File and variable has some values similar but not in same order.

Comment: The quotes are part of the variable or just for representation? Also post your research attempts so far

Comment: [BashFAQ #36](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/036) is closely related.

Comment: BashFaq is very helpful

Comment: Downvoting Ninjas so swift, they won't leave a comment behind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't care about ordering, one of the cleanest ways to maintain a set is with an associative array. This gives you O(1) ability to check for or remove items -- much better performance than you'd get with `sed`

```
## Convert from a string to an array
str="abc.def.ghi aa.bbb.ccc kk.lll.mmm ppp.qqq.lll"
read -r -a array <<<"$str"

## ...and from there to an *associative* array
declare -A items=( )
for item in "${array[@]}"; do
  items[$item]=1
done

## ...whereafter you can remove items in O(1) time
while IFS= read -r line; do
  unset "items[$item]"
done <file

## Write list of remaining items
printf 'Remaining item: %q\n' "${!items[@]}"
```

By the way, much of this code could be skipped if the original data were in associative-array from to start with:

```
# if the assignment looked like this, could just start at the "while read" loop.
declare -A items=( [abc.def.ghi]=1 [aa.bbb.ccc]=1 [kk.lll.mmm]=1 [ppp.qqq.lll]=1 )
```

Comment: Seems like there is no compact way of doing it if you want to do it efficiently. Thanks.

Comment: Most of the space here is spent changing the data format -- if content were stored in an associative array (with the relevant content in the key position) in the first place, things would be much shorter.